# write to resource file under 'resources' directory Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I'm using Spring Boot, trying to test some block of code, which has read son from a file, and then write it there again.
I have a file called `companyConfiguration` in my `test/resources` directory. I'm using `ObjectMapper` class to read and write JSON. How can I get my resource file? I used

```
@Value(value="classpath:companyConfiguration")  
Resource resource;
```

But `resource.getFile()` returns a file under target/test-classes. I don't want to go under target directory in order to make some changes in a file during development. The same result I've got using  `configFile = new ClassPathResource("companyConfiguration").getFile();` and `getClass().getClassloader().getResource("companyConfiguration").getFile()`.
**BUT**
 `getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("companyConfiguration")` returned me correct InputStream (so I could read the value from file under resource directory. ) The only problem is that, as I said before, I`m using ObjectMapper which can write JSON to DataOutput, Writer, OutputStream and File. So, how can I get the source from InputStream and make it target of OutputStream? Or, are there any other workarounds?
Thank you.

Comment: You're confusing a resource, which is a read-only part of your application (think of it as a section of a .exe file, if that helps), and a file on the file system, external to the program, that you could read and write. Your text editor doesn't store the documents it allows to edit inside its executable file, does it? So don't try doing that in your code. If you want to write to a file, then this file must be external to the program, and is thus not a resource that is loaded by the classloader, looking inside your jar file or in a directory in the classpath.

Comment: hmm,thank you, did not think about it.